# What is a conventional way to find the header file corresponding to a C function?

Tags: c, header, c89

I am using `ssize_t` in a piece of C code. I don't know which header file it is declared. So I start googling and then get buried and lost among many unrelated stuff.

This scenario happens over and over again to me, and it wastes much time. So, is there a conventional, probably efficient solution where you professional C coders find the right header file, or maybe you just remember them in mind? Thanks.

Comment: Well there's no standard type called `ssize_type`, so I imagine you'll find it together with the rest of the library that wanted you to use that type. If you know _why_ you are using that type, it should explain itself where to find its declaration.

Comment: Thanks. Typo corrected.

Comment: No better, since `ssize_t` isn't standard either. The standard type `size_t` is found in stddef.h (which in turn is included by many other headers such as stdlib.h).

Comment: @Lundin. Thank you. I did not know that ssize_t is non- standard. Maybe that was the reason I did not find its header!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types don't require a corresponding C file, so that's a bit difficult.

If you know a function that *uses* the type, you can often read it's manual page, and see which headers are needed. For example you might know that `ssize_t` is returned by `read(2)`, and then [the friendly manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read): says:

> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
> ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
> ```

So clearly including `<unistd.h>` must provide a definition of `ssize_t` in addition to the function.

Another approach is grep:ing the system include directories, that's brute force but often helpful.

Comment: maybe you can show the command of how you grep ? BTW, what is the stardard C include directory on a Mac OS?

Comment: @zell Unfortunately there is no standard directory on the Mac.  On mine, I have created a symlink `/usr/include` (which is the old Unix standard, and one I can remember), which points at the actual directory for the current version of clang, which I somehow discovered is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include`.

Comment: @MartinJames  There could be a thousand ways to grep.  SO is such a great place because there are people here who are willing to _share_, and there are people here who are willing to _learn_.  I am unsure what you can do here.